# Mongodb грохнуть коллекцию

Tags: mongodb, recovery

В монгодб есть база, в ней не особо нужная коллекция на сотню гигов. Монгодб обновилась и теперь то ли реиндексирует, то ли восстанавливает базу - всё это очень долго.

Удалить бы эту коллекцию до запуска сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ну можно попробовать стартануть и посмотреть db.currentOp() Там будет список тех операций которые запущены. В них найти создание индекса, если есть, или другую операцию которая долго выполняется. А потом попробовать убить эту операцию db.killOp(), после чего дропнуть коллекцию если надо.
2. По идее есть опция запуска --noIndexBuildRetry которая запрещает запуск переиндексации при старте монги
   https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-noindexbuildretry

Comment: просто оставил на сутки) 
а из файлов коллекцию выкинуть нельзя?